# Authlib OpenID Connect refresh token

Tags: openid-connect, authlib

Regarding https://github.com/lepture/authlib, I would like to return a JWT token in the refresh token response. Is that possible for now ?
I was looking for a `RefreshOIDCTokenGrant` or something like that. Should I do it manually in my `RefreshTokenGrant`?